# Thermodynamics - state variable

Tags: thermodynamics

I am a layman in Thermodynamics. Can anyone please explain to me what is meant by a state variable in a thermodynamical system, in a simple language?

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function) has a pretty succinct definition. Read it and explain what you don't understand about it...

Comment: Honestly, I did go through the first paragraph before posting this question, as I didn't understand a thing in it. There are too many new terms.

Answer (score 2):

A state variable is a quantity which can be determined by the state of the system at a single moment in time.  The temperature, volume, and pressure of a thermodynamic system are examples of this - you can simply measure them, and you don't need any information about precisely *how* the system arrived in its current state.

On the other hand, work (as in, "the amount of work which has been done on the system") is not a state variable, but rather a *process* variable.  Consider a hot ideal gas in a box.  Did it get hot because I put it on top of a flame (i.e. via the addition of *heat*) or because it once had a much larger volume but I rapidly compressed it (i.e. via the application of *work*)?

There's no way to tell without more information about the way the system arrived at the particular state it's in.  Therefore, heat and work, which require a knowledge of the process which created the current state of the gas, are process variables.

Comment: This is an incomplete definition. You should include the notion of *equilibrium* and variable *independence*.